# MongoDB find if field name exists if field name is a special character

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to query if this field exists on any records in the database but it always comes up null, is there any way to find this val

```
users.find({_user: { '*': {"$exists": true } }},).toArray(function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(result);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
users.find({_user: {"$exists": true }}).toArray(function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(result);
);
```

Here is a working snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LzEoeJ2a86L